# T-SQL query to select last 3 months of data, last years month, averages of this month and average of all months

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table with columns `Category, Date, Monthly_Revenue`.

I need a query that will select `Todays_Month`, `Last_Month`, 2 months prior, `Last_years_Month`, average of today's month, average of all months.

This query is needed grouped by category.

Example :

```
Category | Sept, 2012 | Aug, 2012| Jul, 2012 | Sept, 2011 | Average of Sept | Avg all Mo
```

Being fairly new to SQL I still haven't got it yet. I figured see if somebody out there could take a crack at it. Thanks.

**Sample data**

```
'Burger'  '9/1/2012'   '500'
'Fries'  '10/1/2012    '300'
'Burger'  '6/1/2011'   '250'
```

Comment: posting some sample data and the expected result would be very helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Ill do that.

Comment: Scott Weiland would be proud of you if you took a swing at some sample queries first :)  Look at [datediff](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/5e5a4474-31b8-4316-8a34-1e4a5572fb49), [group by](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlgroupby.php) and [avg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx).

Comment: LOL.. Your absolutely correct paul. I think this should be easy as well since its just selecting each data. Would I use a Case statement too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something along these lines .Not the optimum solution but will give you a start
.This is a static solution but it looks like you may want a dynamic solution

*not tested

```
 SELECT 
 Category
,[Sep 2012]=SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TranDate)= YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(TranDate)= MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN Amount ELSE NULL END)
,[Aug 2012]=SUM(CASE WHEN  YEAR(TranDate)= YEAR(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())) AND MONTH(TranDate)= MONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE()))  THEN Amount ELSE NULL END)
,[Jul 2012]=SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(TranDate)= YEAR(DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())) AND MONTH(TranDate)= MONTH(DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())) THEN Amount ELSE NULL END)
,[AVG Sep 2012]=AVG(CASE WHEN YEAR(TranDate)= YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(TranDate)= MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN Amount ELSE NULL END)
,[AVG 12 months]=AVG(CASE WHEN TranDatee > CAST(DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) THEN Amount ELSE NULL END)/12
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Category,Amount
```

Comment: Thanks clearlogic. I was heading that way like a snail. You confirmed it for me.